# Has anyone found a good API to use to get programmatic definitions of words?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for some sort of API where I can POST words I'm interested in and get back responses (ideally in JSON). I'm essentially looking for the Japanese-Japanese version of Jisho.org's fantastic Japanese-English API as detailed here: https://jisho.org/forum/54fefc1f6e73340b1f160000-is-there-any-kind-of-search-api.